# There is a problem with the [problem-user] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, meta, burninate-request

We have the [problem-user](/questions/tagged/problem-user) tag, with excerpt that reads:

> This tag should be used in a question about a user who has been causing problems like spamming, unproductive answers, using abusive language and starting comment wars.

While technically valid and "nice to have" tag that might add meta info to the question, I don't feel comfortable with the phrase itself "problem user", which might encourage people to mention the specific user when posting the question, which isn't good and isn't allowed.

The combo [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) with [users](/questions/tagged/users) is good enough, and fits perfectly to describe a question about users who have problematic behavior. The [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse) tag excerpt says:

> This tag is for questions concerning actions leading to bad behaviors or bad purposes, considered or suspected to be against Stack Exchange policies or the collaboratively philosophy of any Stack Exchange site.

Which should fit questions about users as well.

Should we burninate the [problem-user](/questions/tagged/problem-user) tag and replace it (if relevant) with the above two tags instead?

Comment: @Rubén well with your rep you can suggest such a synonym, yes. Personally not a fan of synonyms in general, so staying out of it, but nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @Rubén, I think that more correct synonym, if synonym to be created, will be [problem-user] -> [abuse].

Comment: @Rubén well, but problematic usually means abusive in some way. Anyway it's case-by-case, I agree.

Comment: Tagging this with [tag:problem-user] is so tempting/fitting ;)

Answer (score 11):

Well, I'm an oldschool mod, and I learnt we don't deal with problem *users*, we deal with problem behaviours. I think synonymising abuse to problem users feels 'better' than behaviour, since behaviour can also cover network culture that's positive or neutral.

The users tag seems implicit and slightly meta taggy to me, but that's another problem.

---

I feel like there's reasonable support to fix this.

So the game plan now is to do a quick check to see if there's any unforeseen problems go through and retag anything that doesn't 'fit' abuse, then do a tag syonymation, I hope to get it done over the weekend, so if its not done by say tuesday, give me a poke.

---

I removed the tag from 4 posts where abuse felt in appropriate as a tag and ran a merge. The tag is gone.

[image: tag has been burninated]

Comment: This has +10, -0. What is the next step?

Comment: Well, doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the hard work!

Comment: As upvoting the previous thanks comment doesn't sound enough, I went down the rabbit hole a bit :P We have several posts with innovative names for naming user behaviors, some positive, [tag:experts], some negative, and some just giving names to roles played. Not all share a tag, i.e. , [tag:behavior]. Anyway, any suggestions about how to conduct a clean project of posts calling out users instead of focusing on behaviors? Is it better to flag for mod attention one by one posts calling out a user by name than edit them directly?

Comment: One post, per tag, with an explanation of the expected state - ideally not all at once. It gives time for community review and comment and to keep trac of what's done. That said -  I can't make any promises to getting them done. I might have somewhat less free time in the coming future, and am re-evaluating how, and where I'm choosing to be involved in the network, but the latter is still in the air.